# fnGetData() undefined is not a function error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following code:

```
var jobtable = $('#editjobtable').DataTable();
jobtable.$('tr').click(function() {
var JobKey = jobtable.fnGetData(this);
$('#mykey').val(JobKey[1]);
});
```

I'm using the following libraries:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/mainscript.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I keep getting an error in my google console stating that fnGetData is not a function. I was using it a couple of hours ago to grab table data, so I'm not sure what I did. But any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new at this and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. First of all, I'm dumb. Second, it turns out I was using "DataTable" when I should have been using "dataTable" to get a jquery object.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.